# Error when using Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am now using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON. I follow this tutorial http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/10/how-to-use-alamofire-and-swiftyjson-with-swift-swift-2-ios-9-xcode-7/

My code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tblJSON: UITableView!
    var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tblJSON.dataSource = self

//        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/").response { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
//            print(response)
//            let outputString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
//            print(outputString)
//        }

        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

            if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["contacts"].arrayObject {
                self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
            }
            if self.arrRes.count > 0 {
                self.tblJSON.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrRes.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tblJSON.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = dict["name"] as? String
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dict["email"] as? String
        return cell
    }   
}
```

But it crashed at this line:

```
let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
```

my Pod file:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'UsingAlamofireAndSwiftyJSON' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.2.1'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
end
```

I use Xcode 7.2, Swift 2.1. Any helps would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: By force unwrapping the Optional result from Alamofire with `responseData.result.value!` you're telling the compiler: *"Please crash my app if there is no value."* Your app does exactly what it is told to... // The solution is to read [this chapter of the free online Swift documentation: "Optionals".](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alamofire and SwiftyJSON understand it very well to avoid the force-unwrapping of the optional you can change the response handler to the JSON response handler like this one:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/").responseJSON { response in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .Success(let value):      
            let json = JSON(value)  
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error.description)  
        }
    }
```

With the above code you don't need to unwrap the optional, the force-unwrapping it's not recommended as @Eric said in his comment.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.